# How to create a navigation drawer on a fragment in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I need some suggestions in my design. I have an Activity class that loads multiple fragments. One of the fragment has Navigation drawer. When the user clicks any of the items in the navigation list it loads its fragments and has a back button to come back to the Fragment with the navigation Drawer. 
As shown in the image. A,B, C are items in navigation drawer which would replace the content and has a back button to go back to Fragment D with navigation drawer. 
I have seen multiple tutorials that load navigation drawer in activity and has navigation as main content. What I want is if the use clicks the icon on top it shows the list. Can it be part of the Fragment D layout ?

Any suggestions are appreciated?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a class which is having a navigation drawer in it and then you can extend the particular class wherever you want. if you want it on fragments just extend that particular activity holding those fragments with that class with navigation drawer.

Comment: so can this class(navigation class) be a fragment?

Comment: It is already extending Activity class plus.. I do not want it on all the fragments. Just one Fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a class which is having a navigation drawer in it and then you can extend the particular class wherever you want .... if u want it on fragments then just extend that particular activity holding those fragments with that class with navigation drawer.

No,the activity on which you are replacing fragments should have navigation drawer.that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code,
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="#FFF"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    final String[] data ={"one","two","three"};
    final String[] fragments ={
            "Your.package.Name.FragmentOne",
            "Your.package.Name.FragmentTwo",
            "Your.package.Name.FragmentThree"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

         final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
         navList.setAdapter(adapter);
         navList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
                         drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                                 @Override
                                 public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                                         super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                                         FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                         tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[pos]));
                                         tx.commit();
                                 }
                         });
                         drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
                 }
         });
         FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         tx.replace(R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[0]));
         tx.commit();
    }

}
```

And make your layouts for fragments in this case FragmentOne, FragmentTwo, FragmentThree