# Create navigation drawer on a fragment

Tags: android

I want create a navigation drawer on a fragment
same as this.
[How to create a navigation drawer on a fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332277/how-to-create-a-navigation-drawer-on-a-fragment-in-android)

I have not found a solution,Can anyone give a solution or a example of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by use this library
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer